# How to convert a select tag to label with knockout.js as data-bind

Tags: html, select, knockout.js

I need to change this `select` tag to `label`

However I'm having issues when i change the select tag to label

I already tried changing the select tag to label

```
<select data-bind="mjs: { type: 'SelectMenu', options: [{ text: 'Yes', value: true }, { text: 'No', value: false }], selectedValue: buyProgramVM.bpDetails().PurchaseBPDetails.Primary.IsOwnsHome, dataType: 'bool',disabled:!buyProgramVM.enableRunBP() || buyProgramVM.bpDetails().isFinalized() , readonly: !buyProgramVM.enableRunBP() || buyProgramVM.bpDetails().isFinalized() }" style="width: 60px; margin-left: 9px"></select>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by changing `select` to `label`? What should happen to `options` and `selectedValue`?

Comment: Are all 3 sentences exactly the same or is it just me?